# How to emit more than one item on error return in RxJava2?

Tags: android, error-handling, rx-java2

I want to handle exception by emitting 2 items.
I would like to have something like

```
handleHttpResponse(): Observable()
LoadingOn, LoadingOff, OnError(error): Item

aHttpObservable()
    .flatMap{ handleHttpResponse() }
    .startWith{ Observable.just(LoadingOn) }
    .concatWith{ Observable.just(LoadingOff) }
    .onErrorReturn{ error -> Observable.just(LoadingOff, OnError(error)) }
```

Or since both `onComplete` or `onError` I have to close the loading dialog, may I have something like

```
aHttpObservable()
    .flatMap{ handleHttpResponse() }
    .startWith{ Observable.just(LoadingOn) }
    .onTerminate{ Observable.just(LoadingOff) }
    .onErrorReturn{ error -> OnError(error) }
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onErrorResumeNext()`

```
Observable.error(new RuntimeException("test"))
        .onErrorResumeNext(error -> {
            return Observable.just("a_message", error.toString());
        })
        .subscribe(System.out::println);
```